# how long can I store beet brine in fridge

Tags: storage-lifetime

Can I use the pickling brine I made last year for beets this year. I kept it in a sealed mason jar in the refridgerater, but I did not process it in a hot water bath. Is this brine safe to use for pickled beets this year ?